# Create NSMutableArray from NSArray with recursion

Tags: macos, recursion, nsmutablearray

What I am trying to do is display an editable tree structure (using NSOutlineView and NSTreeController) of a tree that is stored in user defaults. It is straightforward to load the tree into the outlineview but, since all of the nodes are immutable objects, adding children through the UI or even changing the value of an existing node name fails. I can easily create a mutable copy of the initial array but then only the top-level nodes are mutable, not the lower-level ones.

So my question is: how to create a mutable version of an immutable array in which all of the nested sub objects are also mutable?

The structure of the user default data is an Array of Dictionaries where each Dictionary has a String value with key "name" and, optionally, an Array with key "children". The "children" Array has the same structure (i.e. Array of Dictionaries, …).

Comment: You could cheat it by serializing it as JSON and deserializing it with the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` flags. It won't perform necessarily well, but it is a simple and effective solution.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I'll take a look at this; but it shouldn't be too hard to write a recursive function to handle deserialization - I'm working on that now. (Of course, serializing is just one line of code to issue setObject on NSUserDefaults for the array keyname).